# Javascript function, css keyframe not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to move my robot to the right by toggling between two classes, but it doesn't seem to be working. Please help. Created two classes and was trying to switch between two of those classes with toggle but not working.

```js
function moveR() {
  let robot = document.getElementsByClassName("robot1");
  robot.classList.toggle = "moveRight";
}
```

```css
.robot1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#moveRightBtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  font-size: 20px
}

.moveRight {
  animation-name: moveRight;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

@keyframes moveRight {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 id="Header1">Keyframe Practice</h1>
<h2>Moving The Robot To Right</h2>

<img class="robot1" src="https://cdn-icons.flaticon.com/png/512/630/premium/630426.png? 
        token=exp=1636183057~hmac=45b700055844fa031977edfa2ee4457b">

<button onclick="moveR()" id="moveRightBtn">Move Right</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

Your code has two major problems.

1. `getElementsByClassName` returns an array. You just want the first element. An alternative method is by using `querySelector(".robot1")` that returns the first match.
2. `classList.toggle` is a function, you don't have to assign (with `=`) the class, but pass it as parameter.

These the two changed lines in your code, everything else is fine:

```js
  let robot = document.querySelector(".robot1");
  robot.classList.toggle("moveRight");
```

#### Working Demo

```js
function moveR() {
  let robot = document.querySelector(".robot1");
  robot.classList.toggle("moveRight");
}
```

```css
.robot1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#moveRightBtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  font-size: 20px
}

.moveRight {
  animation-name: moveRight;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

@keyframes moveRight {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 id="Header1">Keyframe Practice</h1>
<h2>Moving The Robot To Right</h2>

<img class="robot1" src="https://cdn-icons.flaticon.com/png/512/630/premium/630426.png? 
        token=exp=1636183057~hmac=45b700055844fa031977edfa2ee4457b">

<button onclick="moveR()" id="moveRightBtn">Move Right</button>
```

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to set the answer as accepted :)

Comment: `let robot = document.querySelector(".robot1");` is more readable

Comment: That's true, I'll update the answer. Thanks!